# Minimum writeonly permissions needed for a queue in rabbitmq using masstransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have two console applications. One consumer and one producer. Both have their own user. There is one queue in a separate virtual host. Now I want to set queue permissions of the producer to writeonly, but when i remove the configuration and read permissions an exception is thrown

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=403, text='ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange ...
```

When i put the .* back in the configuration section of the permission the exception disappears. Which regular expression should i use as a minimum for the configuration permission to let masstransit work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit requires full permissions to RabbitMQ, since every instance will create exchanges and/or queues and may read and/or write. There is no "send-only" version of MassTransit.